# ¿Cómo puedo quitar las comas cuando se produce un array asociativo de dos existentes y luego a esta unión se le introducen elementos por prompt?

Tags: javascript, array, push, concat

Existen 2 arrays y se realiza la unión de ellos a través de .concat y luego se añaden elementos mediante un prompt, pero el problema se suscita cuando se va a mostrar el resultado y allí es donde aparecen una coma al principio del resultado. Entiendo que estamos hablando de un array asociativo al que luego se le añaden elementos por prompt, pero se trató de resolver de la misma manera incluso declarando un array vacío que era llenado por los elementos provenientes del prompt y luego volver a hacer otra unión con la de los dos primeros otra vez con .concat pero seguía saliendo la coma al principio del resultado. Las comas son producto de que existen dos arrays (o elementos) y al unirse Javascript los toma como elementos separados y por eso les añade las comas para diferenciarlos por separado, pero no encuentro la solución.

```js
const mananaPoderosa = ["Hidratarse", "Meditar", "Desayunar saludable"]
const cerrarDia = ["filtros de luz azul", "leer", "Dormir con tiempo"]
const ambasRutinas = mananaPoderosa.concat(cerrarDia);
const todoList = [" "]
// Presentación
let nombreUsuario = prompt(`Bienvenido a tu To-do list, estoy hablando con...`)
// Rutinas predefinidas
alert(`${nombreUsuario} ¿Quieres agregar alguna de estas rutinas predefinidas a tus tareas?`)
let rutinaPredefinida = prompt(`"Mañana poderosa" incluye: Hidratarse, meditar y desayuno saludable
"Cerrar día" incluye: filtros luz azul, leer y dormir con tiempo. 
Si deseas "Mañana poderosa" escribe 1, si deseas "Cerrar día" escribe 2, si deseas ambas escribe 3, pero si no quieres ninguna, escribe cualquier otro valor`)

if (rutinaPredefinida == 1) {
    todoList.push(mananaPoderosa)
} else if (rutinaPredefinida == 2) {
    todoList.push(cerrarDia)
} else if (rutinaPredefinida == 3) {
    todoList.push(ambasRutinas)
} else {
    alert(`Okey! No agregaras ninguna "Rutina predefinida" a tu To-Do List`)
}

// Agregar tareas propias
function agregarTarea() {
    let cantidadTareas = prompt(`¿Cuantas tareas propias quieres agregar?`)
    for (let i = 0; i < cantidadTareas; i++) {
        let agregar = prompt("Escribe aquí una tarea")
        todoList.push(agregar)
    }
}

agregarTarea()

// Consulta y estado final
let consultaFinal = prompt(`¡Estas son tus tareas:  ${todoList}! 
Si quieres remover la última tarea escribe: 1 (las rutinas predefinidas se borran todas juntas)
Si quieres agregar una tarea escribe: 2
Si no quieres hacer cambios, escribe cualquier otro valor`)

if (consultaFinal == 1) {
    todoList.pop()
} else if (consultaFinal == 2) {
    agregarTarea()
} else {
    alert(`¡Estas son tus tareas:  ${todoList}!`)
}
```

Comment: Tu const todoList = [" "]; le estas iniciando el valor de la primera posicion al crearla, deberia ser , const todoList = [];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Descripción

Estas inicializando el array con un valor que es una cadena vacía. lo que provoca que se vea ese elemento al principio.

Al utilizar [plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (o template literals), por defecto, los valores que son interpolados cuando se usa `${valor}` son convertidos a su representación en `string`. Esto para arreglos se lleva a cabo utilizando el método [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString).

Como tu arreglo `todoList` tiene un elemento al inicio, cuando lo muestras, te agrega el elemento al principio.

### Problema

Por lo tanto, el problema en si no es que aparece una coma al principio, sino que pareciera que hay una coma al principio, pero en realidad está el elemento vacío `"  "` al principio del array.

### Solución

```js
const mananaPoderosa = ["Hidratarse", "Meditar", "Desayunar saludable"];
const cerrarDia = ["filtros de luz azul", "leer", "Dormir con tiempo"];
const ambasRutinas = mananaPoderosa.concat(cerrarDia);

const todoListSinElementoVacio = []; // Elimina el elemento del arreglo
const todoListConElementoVacio = [" "];

todoListSinElementoVacio.push(ambasRutinas);
console.log(`Sin elemento vacio: ${todoListSinElementoVacio}`);

todoListConElementoVacio.push(ambasRutinas);
console.log(`Con elemento vacio: ${todoListConElementoVacio}`);
```

```js
const mananaPoderosa = ["Hidratarse", "Meditar", "Desayunar saludable"]

const cerrarDia = ["filtros de luz azul", "leer", "Dormir con tiempo"]

const ambasRutinas = mananaPoderosa.concat(cerrarDia);

const todoList = [] // <- Elimina el elemento "  " y listo
// Presentación
let nombreUsuario = prompt(`Bienvenido a tu To-do list, estoy hablando con...`)

// Rutinas predefinidas
alert(`${nombreUsuario} ¿Quieres agregar alguna de estas rutinas predefinidas a tus tareas?`)

let rutinaPredefinida = prompt(`"Mañana poderosa" incluye: Hidratarse, meditar y desayuno saludable
"Cerrar día" incluye: filtros luz azul, leer y dormir con tiempo. 
Si deseas "Mañana poderosa" escribe 1, si deseas "Cerrar día" escribe 2, si deseas ambas escribe 3, pero si no quieres ninguna, escribe cualquier otro valor`)

if (rutinaPredefinida == 1) {
    todoList.push(mananaPoderosa)
} else if (rutinaPredefinida == 2) {
    todoList.push(cerrarDia)
} else if (rutinaPredefinida == 3) {
    todoList.push(ambasRutinas)
} else {
    alert(`Okey! No agregaras ninguna "Rutina predefinida" a tu To-Do List`)
}

// Agregar tareas propias
function agregarTarea() {
    let cantidadTareas = prompt(`¿Cuantas tareas propias quieres agregar?`)

    for (let i = 0; i < cantidadTareas; i++) {
        let agregar = prompt("Escribe aquí una tarea")
        todoList.push(agregar)
    }
}

agregarTarea()


// Consulta y estado final
let consultaFinal = prompt(`¡Estas son tus tareas:  ${todoList}! 
Si quieres remover la última tarea escribe: 1 (las rutinas predefinidas se borran todas juntas)
Si quieres agregar una tarea escribe: 2
Si no quieres hacer cambios, escribe cualquier otro valor`)

if (consultaFinal == 1) {
    todoList.pop()
} else if (consultaFinal == 2) {
    agregarTarea()
} else {
    alert(`¡Estas son tus tareas:  ${todoList}!`)
}
```